# How to Read the inner contents and data of files from other folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-get-contents

I have html files stored in a folder now I want to read all the files and their inner content, data and structure.

I have read all the files as an array from the folder and now I want to know how I can read the inner contents:

```
$this->load->helper('directory');
$dir = "review/sites";
$map = directory_map($dir);
$files = $map;
print_r($files);
```

Comment: You would like to use [file helper](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/file_helper.html) too, in case you want contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read files from a directory and show the inner contents & structure of the files we can use CURL as follows:

```
$this->load->helper('directory'); //Load the directory First
$dir = "review/sites"; //Directory From where you want to read the Files
$map = directory_map($dir);
$files = $map;
   foreach($files as $file){
      $curl_handle=curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'http://localhost/traffictack/review/sites/'.$file);
      curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
      curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
           $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
           curl_close($curl_handle);
             if (empty($buffer)){
                print "Nothing returned from url.<p>";
                }
                else{
                print $buffer;
                }
                }
```

Its Perfectly Worked and Currently i have made this code for codeigniter.